# upload folder to WebDav server using ACConnect WebDav Project

Tags: ios, github, directory, webdav

I have  been searching for WebDav library and found [this](https://github.com/jkichline/ACConnect/tree/master/src/ACWebDAV), ACConnect WebDav Project on github

I am able to upload and download image/files. I have not been able to figure out how to upload a folder. If anybody has any ideas please share :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so found out that we cannot upload the complete folder directly using this library.

There is function `[propReq createCollection:filePath];` which enables us to create folder on webdav server. Then we will need to upload files one by one to this newly created folder. In terms achieving uploading of complete folder :)